# How to extract attention from MultiHeadAttention

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, attention-model

I'm implementing the transformer model for time series classification seen in the  [keras website](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/). After being able to run the model with my data, I was wondering how could I analyse the attention given by the transformer. After I saw the information about the function I realized I could take the attention_scores if I attribute True to return_attention_scores, so basically this:

```
def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0):
    # Normalization and Attention
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(inputs)
    output_tensor, weights  = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
    )(x, x, return_attention_scores=True)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(output_tensor)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(res)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    return x + res
```

Now, however, i'm stuck and I don't know how can I take the scores after the training is done. Can anyone shed a light on this?

Comment: initialize a dictionary name `weight = {}` outside of the function scope and then assign the `attentions` to this dictionary `output_tensor, weights['attention_score']  = layers.MultiHeadAttention(key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout)(x, x, return_attention_scores=True)` and when the training is done then simply print that dict.

Comment: @MohammadAhmed I did that but it only printed something like this:
`{'attention_score': <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 4, 10, 10) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'multi_head_attention')>}`
for the number of heads I have, so it printed 4 lines like this in my case

Comment: do it like this `print(weights['attention_score'])`

Comment: @MohammadAhmed now I got this:
`KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4, 10, 10), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='multi_head_attention/softmax/Softmax:0', description="created by layer 'multi_head_attention'")`